# When retargeting project from .NET 4.5 to .NET 2.0, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform cannot be loaded

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Our webserver is currently running/utilizing .NET 2.0 for applications running on it. I've created a few websites for my boss with ASP.NET and Visual Basic; I'm new to the platform, but my websites have come out great. I simply used Visual Studio to create a New Empty ASP.NET Web Application each time and went from there.

He has said that he would like to switch to 4.5, but I understand not wanting to cause any disruption in service. This leaves me having to retarget both of my web applications to .NET 2.0. The only problem that I'm currently having is an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I have used NuGet Package Restore (as said online) and I have manually "Install-Package/Update-Package -reinstall" Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, but it still throws the exception. I even created a new project, targeted to 2.0, created a Web Forms page, ran it, and *still* received the error.

Any help would be beyond greatly appreciated. There may just be something I'm totally missing because I'm new to the platform.

Comment: All new stuffs in the past five to ten years focus on .NET Framework 3.5 and above (especially 4.5 and above). If your boss does not realize that fact, I suggest you remind him/her.

Comment: @LexLi He certainly does recognize the need to change, but luckily my application didn't depend on anything _after_ 2.0. Is there any significant improvement that I should know of after 2.0? I do know that my issue was due to the DotNetCompilerPlatform not coming until 3+ years after 2.0. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Though this doesn't exactly answer your question, you need to know that different web apps on the same IIS server can use different versions of the .NET framework.

Simply set each web app to use a different app pool, and then set the framework of the app pool to what you need.  Of course, it should be set to what the app expects.

Answer (score 0):

Just to come back to this and close it out once-and-for-all, it's not possible to do what I was trying to do. The code in the 4.5.2 .NET project was being compiled by what I linked in the question,

> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

For whatever reason, retargeting to .NET 2.0 required me to make a new project that was initially targeted to 2.0 (without retargeting) and then dump my files into *that* project. Which worked seamlessly.